# google firestore - get DuplicateFileException

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Please give me advice. I've just followed this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and from this line `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.25.0-beta'` 
nothing is working.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties
>
> File1: C:\some.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-core\1.7.0\453cc89cde3f2896825aecfb4d05dc2ba06f9775\google-cloud-core-1.7.0.jar
>
> File2: C:\some.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-firestore\0.25.0-beta\7258a705784332ebc9be97f28be93b3e6548073f\google-cloud-firestore-0.25.0-beta.jar

But I haven't imports `google-cloud-core` in my `gradle` file. Here is output from `gradle`:

```
    dependencies{

        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.25.0-beta'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide says:

Add the Cloud Firestore Android library to your `app/build.gradle` file:

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'`

Comment: Right com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore is the server-side java SDK, not an Android SDK. Though the surface APIs look similar they're very different under the covers.